# Security disadvantages of sending a password with GET?

Tags: web-application, http

Other than over your shoulder peeping, if a password is sent using GET in plaintext over an encrypted connection, are there any extra security disadvantages or is it the same as POST?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is really a duplicate. The linked question is marked as a duplicate of a question which asks if GET parameters are encrypted when using HTTPS. This question seems to be more about sending confidential data via GET. But it does seem to be a duplicate of [Using GET to submit username/password?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/43470/using-get-to-submit-username-password)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No confidential data should ever be sent via GET.

The data may be leaked or stored by:

- **referers** if you link to a different page after a login
- **your server logs** which is an issue if these logs are ever available, for example via LFI, wrong server configurations, backups, etc.
- **browser histories** which is an issue if multiple people use the same browser - eg in companies or in public libraries -, or even by other websites if history sniffing is an option.
- **proxy servers** that can decrypt the requests
- **users sharing links**

The CWE for this issue would be [CWE-598](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/598.html).

Comment: Great answer! I would like to add that some frameworks don't do CSRF checks on GET requests. That would open up the webapp to login CSRF.

Comment: @Anders very good point. And frameworks have a good reason not to do CSRF checks on GET requests. If a CSRF check would be performed, the CSRF token may be leaked as well, which is why all requests that change state should be POST.